# Как обработать событие в webbrowser только 1 раз? - C#

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста как обработать событие только 1 раз?
Обрабатывается один раз потому-что при клике на элемент вылазиет еще модальное окно и.т.д. И выдает несколько раз element.
В WebBrowser грузится страничка Яндекс Картинки. При клике на какую нибудь картинку я должен получать ссылку для дальнейшей ее обработки.
Но получаю две ссылки с одного клика одинаковых соответственно.

Код:

```
namespace av_export
{

  public partial class MainForm : Form
  {
    public MainForm()
    {

      InitializeComponent();
      webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

            string urlo = "https://yandex.ru/images/search?family=yes&text=красивые+обои";
            webBrowser1.Navigate(urlo);

    }
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
      webBrowser1.Document.Click += webBrowser1_Browser_Mouse_Moved;


        }
    private void webBrowser1_Browser_Mouse_Moved(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
        {
      webBrowser1.Navigating += webBrowser1_Navigating;
      string element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition).GetAttribute("href");
      Debug.WriteLine(element);

            webBrowser1.Navigating += webBrowser1_Navigating;

        }
    private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
  }
}
```

Результат:

```
https://yandex.ru/images/search?text=Suprotec%204660007120727&img_url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.1k.by%2Fimages%2Fproducts%2Fip%2Fbig%2Fpp9%2F5%2F1355337%2Fia33dd4833.jpg&pos=0&rpt=simage&family=yes
https://yandex.ru/images/search?text=Suprotec%204660007120727&img_url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.1k.by%2Fimages%2Fproducts%2Fip%2Fbig%2Fpp9%2F5%2F1355337%2Fia33dd4833.jpg&pos=0&rpt=simage&family=yes
```

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: отписывайтесь от события внутри обработчика и все дела.

Comment: меня одного смущает наличие `webBrowse1.Navigationg +=webBrowser1_Navigating ` дважды? И ниразу не отписывается (т.е. при движении мыши добавляет 2 события)

Comment: Добрый день. Да,это я убрал. Но проблема осталась. Даже при отписке как показано ниже. Все равно выдает 2 ссылки. Как будто я два раза кликаю по элементу

Comment: @alexoander и правда, слона то я и не заметил :) Спасибо! Обновил свой ответ... хотя он можно сказать ваш

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавил отписку от события

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser1;

    public MainForm()
    {
        this.Width = 500;
        this.Height = 500;
        webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser() {Width = 500, Height = 500};


        this.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);


        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

        string urlo = "https://yandex.ru/images/search?family=yes&text=красивые+обои";
        webBrowser1.Navigate(urlo);

    }
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted; // отписка  
        webBrowser1.Document.Click += webBrowser1_Browser_Mouse_Moved;          
    }
    private void webBrowser1_Browser_Mouse_Moved(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {       
        webBrowser1.Document.Click -= webBrowser1_Browser_Mouse_Moved; // отписка   

        webBrowser1.Navigating += webBrowser1_Navigating;
        string element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition).GetAttribute("href");

        Debug.WriteLine(element);

        //webBrowser1.Navigating += webBrowser1_Navigating;

    }
    private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigating -= webBrowser1_Navigating; // отписка

        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но все равно два раза выводит ссылку..

Comment: @technor убрал вторую подписку, попрбуйте ещё раз

Comment: @technor так у вас ещё и Document_completed срабатывает дважды. Обновил код, добавил третью отписку. Проверяйте

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!! Сработало!